# Importing Data with Shiny and RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

Is it possible to load the data from within Shiny (such as a csv file) or does all relevant data need to be in the source code?

I am interested in developing a Shiny App and distributing it, but the data will come from user’s machines, which I would like to load from within Shiny.

If it is not possible to directly load from the Shiny App, what would be the best way for users to specify where the data is?  This is for users with no R experience so I want to make it as easy as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `file.choose()` while the app is starting up (e.g. in server.R before the call to `shinyServer`). Does that help?

Comment: You also mentioned something about an input box in this conversation: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/shiny-discuss/J9aO_MazXQg But I can't find it in the docs.